# How to add input values to arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I am making a distance sensor that lights up a LED-Strip when something is near the sensor. I want to add the latest value measured to an array and make the LED-Strip turn off if none of the 20 latest values are more than 200 (a certain distance away from the sensor). Here is the code:

```
#define DO_Redled 14

int DO_RedLed = 14; //Output D5 (Red Led)
int AI_Pot= 0;

int PotValue = 0;
int brightness = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int values[20] = {};
}

void loop(){
  PotValue = analogRead(AI_Pot);
  analogWrite(DO_RedLed, PotValue);
  Serial.println(PotValue);
  delay(50);
}
```

I've tried some other code, but I didn't understand it and therefore couldn't adapt it to my own code. Any help?

Comment: You can define a global counter "int counter = 0;" and increase this number in every loop and do "values[counter] = PotValue;" in every loop. You can also make a comparison and refresh the counter in the loop

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for help with. You stated what you want to do. You presented the code to do what you want to do. So, you're set, no? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a counter and check if it reach 20

```
 #define DO_Redled 14
 int AI_Pot= 0;
 int PotValue = 0;
 int cont=0;
 int brightness = 0; 
void setup(){ 
    Serial.begin(9600);
   }
 void loop(){
     PotValue = analogRead(AI_Pot); 
     if(PotValue>200)
          cont+=1;
     else
         cont=0;
     if(cont>=20){    
         analogWrite(DO_RedLed, HIGH);   
     }else analogWrite(DO_RedLed,LOW);
     delay(50);
 }
```